# how to make unknown array of vue-model?

Tags: vuejs2

i have a object name question.which is coming from database.i have used v-for with my question object for creating input field.and filing the field the with the question. but i have also a answer field below of question field.i want to use v-model on that answer field. as example i have five question there is five answer field.if i have four question i have four answer field. i don't know for sure how many question field will be there as it is not certain.i want to use v-model with the answer field.as example if there is five answer field i want to create five object of answer filed. how should i do it?

```
    <template>
    <div v-for="(creative_s,index) in question_s_s.creative_s_s" v-if="question_s_s.type=='Creative'">
        <v-textarea
            disabled
            filled
            label="Story"
            rounded
            v-model="creative_s.story"
        ></v-textarea>
        <v-textarea
            label="Answer for Question no 1"
            outlined
            rounded
            v-model=""
        ></v-textarea>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            creative: {},


        }),
    }
</script>
```

question_s_s  is coming by ajax request from database.inside question_s_s i have creative_s_s object there is no problem. i want to use v-model on the answer part.

Comment: Can you provide some code to make your question more clear?

Comment: Are the answers going to be saved as a property on the question object or do you want to store them in a separate data array/object?

Comment: on a separate array/object